# Python not parsing JSON data because of # symbol followed by space?

Tags: python, json

**Note:**

Please see edit below.  This was nothing except a side effect of using a module in a program that could not handle the JSON data format.

I have a JSON feed, from instagram which uses many `#` symbols.  For the most part it has parsed the data fine, but in one case, I received a key value pair that looked like this:

```
    "type": "image",
    "title": "artistsonthelam",
    "text": ""
    My# heart Is With You Always.
    " #laser #installation by #traceyemin# abhk2014",
```

You can see the issue in the `text` field. For some reason the `#` followed by the space (I think) in the `text` key, is causing a problem.  It escapes the text.

Or, the person used quotes in the `text` field, and did not close them, which also escapes the text?
The error i get is `ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 464 column 9 (char 18272)`

Can anybody tell me what the problem is or better yet, how to fix it by either not parsing the text field or fixing the issue with the quotes? Thanks

**Edit:**
I was retrieving this data not through Python but through a module in another program that made HTTP requests that did could not handle JSON correctly.  It did the retrieving, and then I tried to parse the resulting string in Python. The issue was that this module did not fetch valid JSON so that I couldn't parse it correctly.  Thanks for your help and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: quotes in JSON should be escaped - have you tried to replace the inner quotes with `\\"`?

Comment: What you posted is not valid JSON. Not because of the `#`, but because the embedded quotes in the string are not escaped.

Comment: This is from a JSON feed that I am getting online.  This how I receive the feed. Any idea on how I could replace the inner quotes? Thank you

Comment: What API route is this? I'll have a peek if I can reproduce your results. How do you call the API?

Comment: @Startec: That's not instagram, not directly. But using `requests`, *the response loads perfectly*.

Comment: @Startec: what is your code? The response is **fine**; properly formatted valid JSON is returned, with embedded quotes properly escaped.

Comment: @Startec: what, like the one but last entry with ID `0000001397598521000-0000000000010598631`? That's text with `We're bringing #LesLalanne "Moutons" to Hong Kong next month! #regram @artbasel #ABHK2014`. It is fine.

Comment: @Startec: even better, you are showing item 14 from the entries list; it contains U+201C and U+201D quotes (*LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK* and *RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK*), which are not ever going to be interpreted as delimiters for JSON. But your code appears to not handle those.

Comment: Thank you @Martijn, this is a big help, I am cluelesss as to why it is not working. The specific problematic result is `"dbId":"0000001399913341000-0000000000011386717","moderationFlags":{"stageOneModerated":1,"moderated":1}},{"type":"image","title":"artistsonthelam","text":"“My #heart Is With You Always.” #laser #art #love #contemporaryart #artinstallation #installationart #textart #yba #whitecube `  Do you know why those double quotes there causing problems?  All my code is trying to do is `a = json.loads(THAT TEXT)` and i get a ValueError

Comment: @Startec: no, the section is `"\xe2\x80\x9cMy #heart Is With You Always.\xe2\x80\x9d #laser #installation by #traceyemin projected onto the fa\xc3\xa7ade of #thepeninsula #hongkong in #tsimtsatsui. #art #love #contemporaryart #artinstallation #installationart #textart #yba #whitecube #gallery #hk #china #asia #travel @artbasel #abhk2014"`

Comment: @Startec: Can you share us code that shows *how you load the URL* and subsequently try to *load the JSON*?

Comment: Right yes, that section. Those double quotes shouldn't be causing a problem should they?

Comment: I already told you I cannot reproduce your problem. No, the Unicode fancy quotes are not causing a problem.

Comment: I also find the error message puzzling; *there are no newlines in the response*, but the exception talks about *line 464 column 9*. The character position is nowhere near the problematic text either; either as decoded Unicode string or as the original byte string.

Comment: @Startec: can you update your question and update it with your code? Python 3 and `urllib.request` should handle it just fine too.

Comment: @Startec: `response = urllib.request.urlopen(yoururl)`, then `data = json.loads(response.read().decode(response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')))` and your data *loads without problems*.

Comment: @Martin, you were right (all along).  In case you care, I explained my issue above.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a `try`/`except` for `ValueError` and then do a substitution on it like so...

```
try:
    # read the json
except ValueError:
    if ... :  # Somehow check if the json is actually screwed
        re.sub(r'\"([^"]+)\"', "'\1'", json)
```

http://regex101.com/r/lY6zQ7

I assume it doesn't matter if Json key/value pairs are wrapped in ' or ", right?

Comment: No it does not.  These are from instagram tags, so, in this case, someone started their photo's caption with a `"` which broke the JSON. I tried try and catch, and there is an error, can you tell me what I should put in the `if...` part?

Comment: The if clause is optional, you can just do what I put there... But you need to know how to use the `re` module. Go do a quick read on it in the Python doco.

Comment: ehhh, this is for a presentation in one hour. I know I sound like a jackass and  I need to learn regexes, I know, (and I will do a quick read) but for right now is it basically as importing the re module?

Comment: This is a problem with how the OP is handling the Unicode code points in the JSON response; the value in question is `u'\u201cMy #heart Is With You Always.\u201d #laser #installation by #traceyemin projected onto the fa\xe7ade of #thepeninsula #hongkong in #tsimtsatsui. #art #love #contemporaryart #artinstallation #installationart #textart #yba #whitecube #gallery #hk #china #asia #travel @artbasel #abhk2014'`.

Comment: Well I have no idea what error you are getting, so the best thing I could do is refer you to Python doco. It takes 2 minutes to understand how to use `re` and functions such as `sub`... I gave you the regex, you don't need to learn it.